# convert a value from json_decode to a string

Tags: php

how do i convert my value from json_decode to string so i can pass in a the string value to check if an email exists here is my code.

my json is in this format:

```
{email:'test@test.com' }
```

PHP:

```
$var = json_decode($_REQUEST["email"], true);
$result = $membership->CheckEmailAddress($var); // get $var to become a string
```

It looks pretty ugly im just starting php and Im not getting very far aye lol.

jquery:

```
$('#checkemail').click(function () {
    var json = {
        email: $('#email').val()
    };
    $.post('http://' + location.host + '/buyme/include/getemailaddress.php', {
        'email': 'test@yahoo.co.nz'
    }, function (res) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);
        alert(obj.message)
    });
});
```

also how do I put my json variable in my $.post function cose thats the value I want to put there

Comment: If all you are looking for is string format, `serialize` would work for you. -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php  However, `$_REQUEST["email"]` would return a string to begin with.

Comment: You're NOT posting JSON to the server. You don't need `json_decode` on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what value in $_REQUEST["email"] if it's a json value you are showing above then try

your $var is a json object you can fetch email value like not use $var it's an array

tried this :-

```
$val = json_encode(array('email' =>'test@test.com'));
echo $val; //output {"email":"test@test.com"}
$var = json_decode($val, true);
print_r($var); // output Array ( [email] => test@test.com ) 
echo $var['email']; //output test@test.com
```

Comment: im getting errors can you write my code and show me how it should look. I can't understand you're text very well please be clear

Comment: No that doesn't work for me what Im trying to do is get the value posted from email property and then pass it to the CheckEmailAddress then out put the result can you write up for me how todo it cos Im having real trouble getting somewhere please